# C# ODP.NET Array Binding an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, odp.net

So I am using ODP.NET and Array Binding to pass multiple objects over in a save function. One of my objects parameters is an array. I didn't want to go down another level and have it be a list of objects itself since it is literally only an array of ID's.

When splitting my list of objects into arrays for each parameter, I am doing this:

```
cmd.Parameters["location"].Value = details.Select(x => x.Location).ToArray();
```

That works when it's just single string, but I am getting an Object Reference error when trying to do an array of IDs.

```
cmd.Parameters["someids"].Value = details.Select(x => x.categoryIDs).ToArray();
```

I've tried to just put it into a string instead of string[] so as not to attempt to convert a string[][] into a string[] (I think that's the problem when doing the binding).

```
cmd.Parameters["someids"].Value = details.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.categoryIDs)).ToArray();
```

Is there a way to pass comma delimited values through array binding? To be specific, I'm array binding the `details` object that just happens to have an array as a parameter.